# Is there a way to limit to only 1 row per column value in a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm filtering some data where say table.x has the following structure

```
column1 | c.2 |column3

0.0.0.0 | 20 | 2019-04-29 14:55:52
0.0.0.0 | 10 | 2019-04-29 14:45:52
0.0.0.0 | 50 | 2019-04-29 14:35:52
0.0.0.0 | 50 | 2019-04-29 14:25:52
0.0.0.0 | 90 | 2019-04-29 14:15:52
0.0.0.1 | 40 | 2019-04-29 14:05:52
0.0.0.1 | 40 | 2019-04-29 13:45:52
0.0.0.1 | 70 | 2019-04-29 13:30:52
0.0.0.4 | 20 | 2019-04-29 13:25:52
```

I would like the result set to return as

```
0.0.0.0 | 20 | 2019-04-29 14:55:52
0.0.0.1 | 40 | 2019-04-29 14:05:52
0.0.0.4 | 20 | 2019-04-29 13:25:52
```

Comment: Why those rows and not the others with the same IPs? You need to be able to describe that for the database to provide them.

Comment: RichardHuxton I need one for each ip there can be multiple ip's

Comment: you want a SQL statement or a Java program to do that?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I wanted a statement. Got help thanks.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the max `column3` for each `column1` by grouping and then join to the table:

```
select t.*
from tablename t inner join (
  select column1, max(column3) column3
  from tablename
  group by column1
) g on g.column1 = t.column1 and g.column3 = t.column3
```

Comment: This will of course give you multiple rows when you have duplicate timestamps in column3. That might or might not be what you intended. If it is what you intended, please add a clarification to your question or a comment here if you can't edit the question.

Comment: That's was not the intention, I need just one

Answer (score 3):

What about using `DISTINCT` with one column like so :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (column1) column1, column2, column3 FROM table_name
```

---

**Note** `c.2` is not a valid column name.

---

Here is a demo online https://rextester.com/FBIS74019

Answer (score 1):

You could usea inner join on max col3 group by column1

```
select * from my_table m
inner join  (
  select  column1, max(column3) col3
  from my_table 
  group by column1 
  ) t on t. column1 = m.column1 and t.col3 = m.column3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following SQL code:

```
SELECT max(column1), column2, max(column3)   --maximum of IP address and time
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY column1                             --grouped by IP address
```

The result is:

```
max(column1)  |  column2  |  max(column3)
------------------------------------------------
0.0.0.0          20          2019-04-29T14:55:52Z
0.0.0.1          40          2019-04-29T14:05:52Z
0.0.0.4          20          2019-04-29T13:25:52Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use window function

```
select 
    column1, column2, column3
from (
    SELECT 
        column1, column2, column3,
        row_number() over ( partition by column1 ) pbg
    FROM tablename
) aaaa
where aaaa.pbg = 1
```